# Create NDSI from 'MODIS/006/MOD09GA' for given interval of time?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I created a masked NDSI from Modis Terra/500m reflactance daily product at a 10 days interval for given period. I adapted a function from previous posts  to iterate through my collection to create this NDSI. My problem is that for example if I give my code origin date to be 2002-02-01(date from where my iteration will begin) i get back a result for the first ten days in the interval (1-10 of the month, as i wanted) but the next result will be on the 2002-02-21 and another on 2002-03-03 but my desired result must be on 2002-03-01.
I want to have 3 NDSI per month, one for 1-10 period, one for 11-20 and last one for 21-through last of every month that I want (ignore their number of days, 28,30 or 31 days for months respectively). Can someone help me with some insights?

My code is here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ad38d0f25d06048de8612a6225cc9cd6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a very good definition of the end and start dates to loop over.
For the last dates of the months, make use of the fact that the end date is exclusive. Thus, just use the first day of the next month.

I would make the function as follows:

```
//define starting and ending dates
var startyear = 2001;
var endyear = 2003;
var mapYears = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear);
var startmonth = 11;
var endmonth = 4; 
var mapMonths = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear, startmonth, 1);
var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear, endmonth+1, 1); // end date is always exclusive

// define list of dates to filter on
var startdays = ee.List([1, 11, 21]);
var enddays = ee.List([11, 21, 1]);
// Create a sequence of numbers, one for each time interval.
var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, 2);

//function to iterate through images and 
//reduce to max value per pixel, for defined interval

var collect = function(collection, start, end, mapYears, mapMonths) {
  // map over the years
  var images = mapYears.map(function(year){
    // map over the months
    var images1 = mapMonths.map(function(month){
      // map over the day range
      var images2 = sequence.map(function(dayRange){
        var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, startdays.get(dayRange));
        var endDate = ee.Date(ee.Algorithms.If({condition: ee.Number(dayRange).eq(2),
                          falseCase: ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, enddays.get(dayRange)),
                          trueCase: ee.Algorithms.If({condition: ee.Number(month).eq(12),
                                  trueCase: ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1), 1, enddays.get(dayRange)),
                                  falseCase: ee.Date.fromYMD(year, ee.Number(month).add(1), enddays.get(dayRange))
                                  })
                          }));
        return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                          .reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
                          .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
                          .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
      });
      return images2;
    });
    return images1;
  }).flatten();

  // make an image collection from the list of images
  collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images);
  // filter out the images outside the time range
  return collection.filterDate(start, end);
};


var luni = collect(NDSI, start, end, mapYears, mapMonths);
print('1',luni)
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/91a3374c769e82963beec4d7b0c1f463)